# How to clone HtmlElement in C# WinForms application?

Tags: c#, html, css, winforms

In a C# WinForms application I'm using a Web browser control in which i view some HTML designs.

I could change html element attributes through code then edit.

However, i could not clone html element to re-add them to html page again.
I tried following code :

```
            HtmlElement old_element = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("element1");
            HtmlElement new_element = my_element;
            new_element.Style = "background-color:orange;";
            my_element.Parent.InnerHtml += new_element.OuterHtml;
```

When running code background color is applied to both `old_element` and `new_element`.

I want changes to be applied only to `new_element` while preserving old element as it is.

Is that possible without dealing with element html as text ?

Comment: What you are doing atm is passing down reference with `HtlmElement new_element = my_element;` this doesn't create a new object and thats why changes apply to both. this is a duplicate of [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects)

Comment: I just was trying to explain what i wanna do. Tried this solution but it gives error that this object cannot be serialized

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work with HTMLElement